# Right-to-left text in SSH is inconsistent

Tags: ssh, terminal, right-to-left

I am using SSH to connect to a server, where on occasion I need to work with some right-to-left language (e.g. Arabic).

When I use *some* console software (e.g. `lxterminal` or `xfce4-terminal`), it works out just fine. In other terminals the text is backwards. Moreover, this behaviour is not even consistent across different computers (the `xfce4-terminal` behaves differently at home and in my office).

What's worse is that the terminals are fine. Local files are displayed correctly. It is only when I connect via SSH that the problem occurs.

So... what's the problem? Where is coming from? Is it the SSH, or the terminal, or somehow both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's worse is that the terminals are fine.

I doubt so. This is a much more complex story than you probably think. Terminals behave differently, and one's behavior might be right-to-left friendly with a certain set of applications, while others' behavior might be RTL friendly with another set of apps.

> Local files are displayed correctly.

Again, it highly depends on what you mean by "displayed": do you `cat` them, or open with `vim`, `emacs`, `less`, some other application, etc. Maybe with some terminals `cat` gives the expected result and `vim` the unexpected one, with other terminals the other way around.

---

You might be interested in [this](https://terminal-wg.pages.freedesktop.org/bidi/), an about 50-page long technical document studying the situation and proposing a way to address the problems, so that a terminal can support multiple modes, and as such support the seemingly contradicting requirements of different kinds of apps.

VTE version 0.58 implements the proposed solution. VTE is the terminal emulation engine used by `lxterminal` and `xfce4-terminal`, along with many other terminals. Whether you see the "good" or "bad" behavior in these software might thus easily depend on VTE's version. However, again, it's possible that you find the old behavior the "good" one and the new the "bad", depending on what types of applications you test with. In this case, with VTE >= 0.58 you can use the escape sequences mentioned in the document to switch mode, e.g. `printf "\e[8l"` to revert to the old behavior.

---

`ssh` is irrelevant, apart from a software's local or remote version possibly being different.

Comment: At home I'm using Arch, and I have `vte` and `vte3` installed. It seems that the latter is 0.60, and the former is not. I suppose that means that the difference in terminal behaviour comes from difference in underlying engines? (I've removed the `vte` package, but things are still working as they used to an hour ago...)

Comment: A terminal can either use `vte` or `vte3` depending on its source and maybe compile time options, it's never a runtime decision. Check the dependencies in the package manager, or `echo $VTE_VERSION` (empty for the former, the version number as 6000 or so for the latter).

Comment: Both terminals have vte version 6002.

Comment: You've taught me here to always give up on my hopes for a uniform and consistent behaviour of bidi text in consoles. But thank you very much!

Comment: "Hope is not a strategy". Do you want uniform, consistent bidi in terminals and apps? Study my work, send feedback, encourage (ahem sponsor ahem) me to finally finish writing up v0.2 of the doc. Then v0.3 which handles BiDi control chars, along with its implementation in VTE. Work on getting other terminals and terminal-based apps adapt to this spec, by filing bugs, comments, creating patches etc. Or, of course, you can still "hope" (or give up that hope), but that won't move us forward. :-)